# Source for Ramban's perception on death

Tags: sources-mekorot, death, job-iyov-book-of, ramban

I read Rav Gifter's biography, where he states the following:

> The Ramban, in his introduction to *Iyov*, asks a question: *“Why do we cry at a moment of death? “Why do we shed tears? This is the natural state of things. Men are born. They live. They die. What is there to cry about?*
>
> *The holy Ramban says that this is not the natural state of things. It’s wrong! Men were made to live forever and ever, in the joy and the Countenance of G-d in Gan Eden. Death signifies that things are not working according to the natural course of Creation. It is something unnatural and not ordinary. This is why we are moved to tears. Did we ever give thought of this approach to crying?*
>
> *The Ramban was also bothered by the natural course of things. Naturally, we should be in Gan Eden, enjoying the proximity, the friendship, the closeness, and the love of Hashem Yisbarach. But why do we seem so far removed? Because sin brought death into this world. This is what brings men to tears.* (*Rav Gifter* by Rabbi Yechiel Spero, pages 361 – 362)

Does anyone know where the Ramban says this in his introduction to *Iyov*?

Comment: FYI - Related to this, you may want to read Rabbeinu Yona's explanation on Pirkei Avot (I think it's in Ch. 5) "Keter Shem Tov". He asks a similar question. Makes sense, considering that R. Yonah was a big follower of Ramba"m (after R. Yonah did teshuva).